# Flot Chart loses data when jQuery Flippy used

Tags: javascript, flot, flippy

I have been searching all over to find a solution for my problem. I have a Flot line chart that is inside a jQuery Flippy div. I basically wanted to have the Flippy so that you could switch between a chart and a table with a cool effect.

The button to start the Flippy works fine and just shows a simple div for now. However, when you click the other button to reverse the Flippy (go back to the chart), the data on the chart has gone. The axis and labels are there, but there is no line. I'm not sure whether you have to redraw the chart, I have tried lots of ways of creating a button to redraw the chart, ideally I would like it to redraw the chart when you click the button to reverse the Flippy.

This is the js code I have for the Flippy buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn-reverse").on("click",function(e){
        $(".flipbox").flippyReverse();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btn-top").on("click",function(e){
        $(".flipbox").flippy({
            color_target: "#b6d635",
            direction: "top",
            duration: "200",
            verso: "<span style='height:300px' class=\"big\">Other side of Flippy<br><br><br><br><br><br></span>",
         });
         e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

This is the js that creates the chart in the first place when the page loads (it is included in a separate PHP file):

```
var plot = $.plot($(".chart"),
       [ { data: sin, label: "Total cost ", color: "#ee7951"} ], {
           series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, 
                    tickFormatter: currencyFormatter },
           xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: '%b %y',                
            }
       });
```

Finally this is the HTML that renders the chart and also the two buttons for the Flippy and Flippy reverse.

```
<a class="btn" id="btn-top" href="#">Flip</a>
<a class="btn" id="btn-reverse" href="#">Reverse</a>


<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="flipbox-container">
      <div class="span11">
        <div class="widget-box flipbox">
          <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-signal"></i> </span>
            <h5>Total Usage Costs</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="widget-content">
            <div class="chart"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could advise why the chart loses it's data when you use a Flippy or suggest how I could make the chart redraw when the Flippy reverse button is pressed, it would be very helpful.

Comment: So the chart starts out visible, and looks fine, but when you flip back and forth, then it's gone?  Also, what browser & version are you using, and what version of Flot?

Comment: Hi, that's right, the chart looks fine to start with then once you flip and then flip back to the chart the line is gone. The axis and labels are fine. I have tried it in Chrome 28, Firefox 22 and IE10 all with the same results. The version of Flot is v.0.7. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have also just tried the latest version of jquery.flot.min.js (version 0.8.1) and it is still the same issue.

Comment: There's a bug in Chrome 28 where canvas elements sometimes don't render, but if you're seeing the same behavior on other browsers then that's not it.  Not familiar with Flippy's internals, all I can suggest is that you might work around the problem by redrawing the plot whenever the Flippy flips.